# Thread 1: signal SIGINT when getting a value from NSDictionary

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get values from NSDictionary using the inbuilt get() func, but each time i use the get func the app crash, and xcode doesn’t print any message except "Thread 1: signal SIGINT".
but, when I try get the value directly by using dicName["key"], it does work.
does anyone has an explanation for this, and how can i fix this issue?

```
func getLanguageLabel(origValue:String, key:String) -> String{
    let langs:NSDictionary! = GeneralFunctions.languageLabels
    //this works fine
    let lang = langs[key]
    //this makes the crash!
    let lngValue = langs.get(key)
    return lngValue
}
```

the get func in the extension

```
extension NSDictionary{
func get(_ key:String) -> String{

    let value = self.value(forKey: key)
    
    if(value != nil){
        return String(describing: value!)
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don’t use `NS…` collection types in Swift. Use native types.

Comment: @vadian it wasn’t me who used the NSDictionary, a client came to me with this project, and this project latterly has 12K get() call :) so, i can’t modify all of them.

Comment: Post code as text and not as images

Comment: Maybe it was to long since I used NS types but what is `get()`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I never used it, but i got a project, and the previous developer is using get() to get the value of some key. we usually use: dicName[key], but he is using dicName.get(key)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson and can not simply replace the get call with passing the key inside brackets, because he used the get func nearly 12K time :)

Comment: I can’t find get() in the documentation so I would suggest you find out what it is.

Comment: after all, it seems that get is an extension :) sorry, did find it in my first search. updated my question.